# Nested list doesn't update item labels when items change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a nested list of `Categories` and their `Products` in SwiftUI. If i tap a `Product`, edit its name and go back to the list, the name doesn't update. The list of products comes from a computed property on the `@FetchRequest`, and not directly from a `@FetchRequest` and i have a feeling im missing a wrapper or something somewhere?

If i add a new Product, then the list updates, because that notifies the `@FetchRequest` that something changes, I'm missing this "magic" for my computed property.

#### My Category

```
extension Category {
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var products: NSSet?

    var sortedProducts: [Product] {
        return self.products.allObjects.sorted({ $0.name > $1.name })
    }
}
```

#### My List

```
List {
    ForEach(categories) { category in
        Section(header: Text(category.name)) {
            ForEach(category.sortedProducts, id: \.self) { product in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ProductFormView(edit: product),
                    label: {
                        Text(product.name)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This `category.sortedProducts` should be stored property, not calculable, so view could observe it and update view correspondingly.

Comment: But it's a dynamic relationship, it needs to be fetched from Core Data and not from a stored property, how to solve this?

Comment: Make a `LabelView(product: product)`  that has `@ObservedObject var product: Product` That way you can observe the changes. Assuming `Product` Is a CoreData object or an  `ObsevervableObject`

Comment: @loremipsum That worked, thank you so much! If you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `LabelView(product: product)` that has `@ObservedObject var product: Product` That way you can observe the changes. Assuming `Product` is a CoreData object or an `ObsevervableObject`